# Bibliography: align text exactly to the author's name

Tags: bibliographies

I have a problem with the Bibliography: the text is aligned to the author's name only in the first 9 entries... when I insert the 10th entry, due to the extra character of the number, the text becomes aligned as in the prevoius case, and I get the following effect:

[image]

How can I align the word "Meccanica" to the beginning of the line after [12]?

P.S.: to create the bibliography, I'm using this code:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\sc \bibitem{met}Bernabai, U., Torella, R.: \it Lezioni di Metallurgia Meccanica.
\sc \bibitem{met}Marchetti, M., Felli, F.: \it Tecnologie Aeronautiche.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Thanks in advice.

Comment: always in the argument following `\begin{thebibliography}` include a number with the same number of digits in the largest reference number.  in this case, `{99}` will do the job.  this argument is what defines the width of the indentation for all the entries.

Answer (score 1):

always in the argument following `\begin{thebibliography}` include a number
with the same number of digits in the largest reference number. in the case
shown here, `{99}` will do the job, assuming that fewer than a hundred
entries are in the bibliography.

this argument is what defines the width of the indentation for all the entries.

if an "alpha" scheme is used to index the bibliography, usually the longest
label should be chosen, but if there are one or two labels that are much
longer than the rest, you may choose to use a shorter one.  in such a case,
the indentation will be set to accommodate the chosen label; for those
entries with longer labels, the default separation will be applied before
the text of the entry, and the indentation of lines after the first will be
the same as for all other entries.  (that is how the example in the question
is behaving.)